# Encontrar caracter en string

Tags: javascript, string

Gracias por leer el post.

Se trata que tengo una función que recibe un string como parámetro. En dicho string tengo que encontrar cuantas veces esta "F" y devolver el numero de veces que está. Mas adelante, en otra función, pasaré otro parámetro para validar ese parámetro, indicando cual letra estoy buscando.

Por lo tanto este es mi código, pero estoy atorado.

```
function contarFs2(string) {
    let contador = 0;
    let caracter = "F"
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i] === caracter);
    contador += contador
}
return contador
}

console.log(contarFs2("FAFFF")); // 4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes que realizar dos cambios:

- Donde pone esto:

  ```javascript
  if (string[i] === caracter);
  ```

  quítale el `;` final. No sirve de nada y detiene el condicional en ese punto, permitiendo que el resto de instrucciones sigan ejecutándose. Es decir, déjalo así:

  ```javascript
  if (string[i] === caracter)
  ```
- Y donde pone esto:

  ```javascript
  contador += contador
  ```

  pon esto:

  ```javascript
  contador += 1
  ```

  para que vaya sumando un elemento en cada iteración coincidente.

Aquí dejo un snippet funcionando:

```js
function contarFs2(string) {
  let contador = 0;
  let caracter = "F"
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i] === caracter)
      contador += 1
  }
  return contador
}
console.log(contarFs2("FAFFF")); // 4
```

Comment: bien, efectivamente funciona, el problema era que el contador no se aumentaba, por que se sumaba 0 + 0?

Comment: Si, sumaba 0+0, pero aunque lo hubieras puesto bien, te daria 5 y no 4 debido al `;` que impedia que el condicional se aplicara a la siguiente línea, por lo tanto siempre sumaba en cada iteración